# Facebook changes the user's id?

Tags: php, facebook

I realize that my facebook id has change from yesterday, same with other facebook accounts(not all yet). I am working with a project which using these ids for some uses. With that changes i have problem with the ids stored in my db. Is there any algorithm remakes the old ids to the new ones?

Comment: What `id` are you talking about? Application ID? User ID? App token? Or something else?

Comment: sorry, i meant user id.

Comment: I'm not seeing any user id changes with the stuff I'm using. Are you sure you're storing them correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook user IDs do not change (nor do IDs for other things - apps, pages, likes, comments, photos, etc. all remain constant).

If you store them as integers, though, longer Facebook IDs are going to turn into 2147483647 (4294967295 if unsigned) on a 32bit system, so it's safest to store them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen personally facebook change the USER ID of a person: http://sht.tl/wfeod1